# rpmbuild fails with "files must begin with /" message

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have to install the binary file using rpm package. I have created the below spec file to install my binary files using a RPM package.

```
-bash-4.1# cat nxtqos.spec
Summary: test Management Utility
Name: test
License: GPL
Vendor: test Limited
Version: 212.0.1.0
Release: 1
%description
%install
cp -rf /home/ahmed/nxtqos/nxtqos /usr/local/bin
%files
nxtqos
-bash-4.1#
```

I am getting below error prompt when I try to create the RPM package with below command.

```
-bash-4.1# rpmbuild --buildroot bnxtqos-tmp/ -bi bnxtqos.spec
error: failed to stat /home/ahmed/nxtqos/bnxtqos.spec: No such file or directory
-bash-4.1# rpmbuild --buildroot bnxtqos-tmp/ -bi nxtqos.spec
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.iuhGJm
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /bnxtqos-tmp '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /bnxtqos-tmp
++ dirname /bnxtqos-tmp
+ mkdir -p /
+ mkdir /bnxtqos-tmp
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cp -rf /home/ahmed/nxtqos/nxtqos /usr/local/bin
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
Processing files: test-212.0.1.0-1.x86_64
error: File must begin with "/": nxtqos


RPM build errors:
    File must begin with "/": nxtqos
-bash-4.1#
```

Can anybody please let me know if I am missing something in the spec file?

Comment: Chris Maes has the correct answer below; however as an FYI, you shouldn't put things in `/usr/local/` either - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#No_Files_or_Directories_under_.2Fsrv.2C_.2Fusr.2Flocal.2C_or_.2Fhome.2F.24USER

Answer (score 2):

in the `%files` section you should provide the complete path to your files where they are to be found when installed:

```
%files
/usr/local/bin/nxtqos
```